# Find $\sum_{k = 0}^{11} \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{11}{k}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

How could I solve this sum using properties from Pascal's Triangle and Pascal's rule?
$$
S = \frac{\binom{11}{0}}{1} + \frac{\binom{11}{1}}{2} + \frac{\binom{11}{2}}{3} + \ldots + \frac{\binom{11}{11}}{12}.
$$

Comment: Hint: Use $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use
$$\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+1} = \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!} = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
to show
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k+1} = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{11}\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{11}{k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{11}\binom{11}{k}\int_0^1x^{k}\, dx=
\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{11}\binom{11}{k}x^k\, dx=\int_0^1 (1+x)^{11}\, dx
$$
by the binomial theorem. The integral can be easily computed.